# Preload PDFs with jQuery and PHP to work with Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-chrome, preloader

I have a page where a PDF is embedded and I'm using a preloader. In Firefox works perfectly, but in Chrome or Safari doesn't. The preload text and image stays only for a second, after that a grey screen appears and stays till the file is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="loading">
        <div class="pretxt">Please be patient, you won't regret!</div>
        <div class="preimg">
            <img src="path/to/image/loader.gif" width="126" height="22" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <embed src="/path/to/file/pdf.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" alt="pdf" id="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function()
        {
        $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Can you please give some advices? Thank you!

Comment: Stick it in an Iframe. Let the browser deal with it "naturally".

Comment: Even if I'm using <object> to embed the file into iframe it's still not working.

Comment: You should just set the SRC to the PDF path and the browser will detect the MINE type and embed it itself.

Comment: Do you mean like this: <object data="/path/to/file/pdf.pdf"> ?

Comment: <iframe src="http://.../myfile.pdf ></iframe>

Comment: With <iframe> it's even worst. Take a look: http://elato.com/pdfviewer/bouquets_die_cuts